# What ~/.config refers to and how to put files there?

Tags: debian, configuration, geany

I want to set up a plugin for the Geany editor on a Debian system. It's a theme changing plugin, so I am following [this manual](http://code.google.com/p/geany-dark-scheme/wiki/InstallGuide). It says:

> The simplest way to do this is to copy the contents of the archive
>   into the ~/.config/geany/filedefs/ folder.

I don't understand this. What do they mean by `~/.config`? Is that the default directory where Geany is installed? I have its files at `/usr/lib/geany` but that doesn't seem to be location they are talking about.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`~` is your home directory, usually `/home/username`.  A file or folder name starting with a `.` is the Linux version of a hidden file/folder. So `~/.config` is a hidden folder within your home directory. Open up your file browser to your home folder, then find the option to show hidden files and folders.  If you don't see `.config`, you'll have to create it.  Then navigate into it, find or create the `geany` folder, go into that, then find or create a folder named `filedefs`. You can then put the relevant files into there.

.config is a convention, defined by [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024114/location-of-ini-config-files-in-linux-unix

Comment: Anything you store in `~/.config` etc will only affect the current user. Use `/usr/share/geany` for global configuration.

Answer (score 2):

`~/.config` is the directory `.config` within your home directory (`~` is shorthand for that directory).